# I would like to know how can I add an image in html when you load a vimeo video?

Tags: html

I would like to know how can I add an image in html when you load a vimeo video ?

Any informartion, links related or codes are welcome.

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are talking about how to add a poster-like utility for Viemo videos, as done trough the `poster` HTML attribute when placing HTML5 videos.

Well, there's no such an option, as far as I know. When Vimeo is not active (as it has not been played yet) the video's thumbnail image is displayed, and when Vimeo's video is loading, it shows it's own loading animation.

Anyway, you can select your custom image when uploading your video on Vimeo, so, at least, by this way you can define what will be showing by default your custom player.